# The programming paradigm behind beginFill/endFill

Tags: history, graphics

The only place I have really noticed this sort of programming style is with the graphics engines. Essentially like [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2370554):

```
graphics.clear()
graphics.setStrokeStyle(myStrokeWidth)
graphics.beginStroke(myStrokeColor)
graphics.beginFill(myFillColor)
for (i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i++) {
  graphics.lineTo(myPoints[i][0], myPoints[i][1])
}
graphics.closePath()
graphics.endStroke()
graphics.endFill()
```

You start the process with `beginFill`, and then do some drawing, and then end with `endFill`. That is, a single piece of functionality (filling the graphics) is done over multiple method calls rather than just one:

```
graphics.fill(...)
```

I don't really know of another place that does it like this, which is why I'm wondering where this paradigm comes from. Wondering if it is for performance reasons, or for some other reason. Also would be interested where else this pops up, but not necessary for the question.

The question is why it's done this way. I would instead just implement it as `graphics.fill(...)`. Under the hood (with the multi-step begin/end paradigm, (oh another sort of similar is with LaTeX or HTML begin/end tags, but not quite the same)), you would have to set a locally global variable (e.g. current graphics context) which would be being modified. It's like doing:

```
var currentFill
graphics.beginFill = function(){
  currentFill = { lineTos: [] }
}
graphics.lineTo = function(point) {
  currentFill.lineTos.push(point)
}
graphics.endFill = function() {
  graphics.draw(currentFill)
  currentFill = null
}
```

Another way of doing it would be passing it in (this seems like how you would do it nowadays):

```
graphics.beginFill = function(){
  return {}
}
graphics.lineTo = function(fill, point){
  fill.lineTos.push(point)
}
graphics.endFill = function(fill){
  draw(fill)
}
```

So wondering if there is some sort of history to this, or if it's an optimization thing or something else. It seems like an anti-pattern because there is hidden state, but not sure.

Comment: By "fill" do you mean to fill the interior of a polygon with a solid color?

Comment: I guess you are overthinking this. There are old, similar concepts like block structure/scope in programming languages, or transactions, but I doubt there is a "single historic source" for this API design - if you want to be sure, you need to ask the API's authors. Moreover, a "graphics context" object can typically have a lot of state variables like current color, current font, current line thickness and so on, which all change the behaviour of the next drawing commands, and I don't see a "fill mode" to be very different from those.

Comment: People did things differently when they were writing C for a 386

Comment: I guess I'm old fashioned...I would simply classify this as idiomatic procedural coding with minimal or no encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

The "paradigm" behind this (if one likes to call it that way) is simply the idea of using **brackets** as a form of grouping. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics)) dates the historic roots of this concept back to 1608.

Specificially for the described use case, I would guess the idea is to avoid having tons of *lineTo* commands which need to be passed all the same `fill` parameter over and over again, which would make the code more "noisy". So yes, it is an "optimization", but not regarding performance, but readability.

Note Python's turtle package seems to have a similar [fill syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#filling). It was inspired by [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))'s turtle graphics, but the original fill syntax in Logo was a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how much further back it goes, but that is very similar to the original Mac QuickDraw API. OpenRgn and CloseRgn.

Basically it’s just a variation on what nowadays gets called the builder pattern.